# HTML: How to Execute setup.exe Process from HTML Web Page

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, activex

I have a bunch of apps on a network drive that I want to allow users to execute from a button click. I have researched the topic but I get an error when I try to build the web page. My boss asked me to do it via web page instead of web app. Not even sure its possible with out doing it as a ASP web app.

code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h1>Test App</h1>
<input id="clickMe" type="button" value="clickme" onclick="RunFile();" />
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

    function RunFile() {
    WshShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
    WshShell.Run("c:/windows/system32/notepad.exe", 1, false);
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is whats in my folder so far:
[image]

I'm getting an error in IE when I test it. I think this code will only work in IE. I read somewhere on here you can only do this using IE. Id like to do it via chrome but I dont you can or have access to to run exe from chrome. Anyway here is error:

```
SCRIPT429: Automation server can't create object
```

I think I'm missing some files or something in order for this to work. I'd honestly prefer to build this as a web app but I have to build it as a html web page first until my boss approves.

Comment: For security reasons, no "real browser" will let you execute programs, no matter if it's on client side or server side. Do you want to run programs on client? Users should download them first and execute them by themselves, there's no way to do that automatically. Do you want to run programs on server? You should develop your project using a server side language and be aware of security risks that this would bring.

Comment: Its an internal web page. It just needs to execute an exe from internal path. Not sure how this is funny or considered a "joke". Converting  simple desktop app to a web based app or as requested as a web page. From what I've read, its possible to do this using IE. IE is not my browser of chose but since its a windows based EXE, its suppose to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can't run an application from a browser window due to security reasons. To execute file, you need to use .HTA applications (which is an HTML application). HTA applications run outside the browser window just like a normal application and have full trust support.

Sample code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Application Executer</title>
    <HTA:APPLICATION ID="oMyApp" 

        APPLICATIONNAME="Application Executer" 

        BORDER="no"

        CAPTION="no"

        SHOWINTASKBAR="yes"

        SINGLEINSTANCE="yes"

        SYSMENU="yes"

        SCROLL="no"

        WINDOWSTATE="normal">
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        function RunFile() {
        WshShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
        WshShell.Run("c:/windows/system32/notepad.exe", 1, false);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="button" value="Run Notepad" onclick="RunFile();"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Output:

[image]

Reference:

[How to execute a Local File using HTML Application?](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/113678/How-to-execute-a-Local-File-using-HTML-Application)

Comment: Still get same error IE: SCRIPT429: Automation server can't create object

Comment: Chrome: html app test.html:23 Uncaught ReferenceError: ActiveXObject is not defined
    at RunFile (html app test.html:23)
    at HTMLInputElement.onclick (html app test.html:29)

Comment: Firefox: The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol. html app test.html

Comment: FireFox: ReferenceError: ActiveXObject is not defined

Comment: This code will only run in IE browser. Go to Internet options -> Security tab -> Local intranet -> custom level  and enabled the 'Initialize and script ActiveX controls not marked as safe for scripting' option. Apply the settings and again try to run the code. Ref: https://appuals.com/how-to-fix-automation-server-cant-create-object-error-on-windows/

Comment: @mholmes, can you please inform the status for this issue? If above answer solved the issue then please try to accept the answer. If you found the solution by yourself then try to post your solution as an answer. If issue still persist then let us know about the current status for the issue. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: I suggest you post your solution as an answer and try to mark your own answer as an accepted answer. It can help other community members in the future in similar kinds of issues. Thanks for your understanding.